# Import data: one column specific value must have, another column several value have too

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Suppose, I want to import data from separate spreadsheetA to spreadsheetsheetB, where Column D have 'play' or 'poetry' or fiction and Column E must have '200'. How it possible?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v_RQvFPxLJSN3k6urCcIXt2BsRlbc-sgaiGAP_aH1Y4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A!A2:M, "where lower(D) matches 'play|poetry|fiction' and E = 200", 1)
```

[image: 0]